# Getting a list of instances in an EC2 auto scale group?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Is there a utility or script available to retrieve a list of all instances from AWS EC2 auto scale group?

I need a dynamically generated list of production instance to hook into our deploy process. Is there an existing tool or is this something I am going to have to script?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I actually ended up writing a script in Python because I feel more comfortable in Python then Bash,

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

"""
ec2-autoscale-instance.py

Read Autoscale DNS from AWS

Sample config file,
{
    "access_key": "key",
    "secret_key": "key",
    "group_name": "groupName"
}
"""

from __future__ import print_function
import argparse
import boto.ec2.autoscale
try:
    import simplejson as json
except ImportError:
    import json

CONFIG_ACCESS_KEY = 'access_key'
CONFIG_SECRET_KEY = 'secret_key'
CONFIG_GROUP_NAME = 'group_name'


def main():
    arg_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=
                                         'Read Autoscale DNS names from AWS')
    arg_parser.add_argument('-c', dest='config_file',
                            help='JSON configuration file containing ' +
                                 'access_key, secret_key, and group_name')
    args = arg_parser.parse_args()
    config = json.loads(open(args.config_file).read())
    access_key = config[CONFIG_ACCESS_KEY]
    secret_key = config[CONFIG_SECRET_KEY]
    group_name = config[CONFIG_GROUP_NAME]

    ec2_conn = boto.connect_ec2(access_key, secret_key)
    as_conn = boto.connect_autoscale(access_key, secret_key)

    try:
        group = as_conn.get_all_groups([group_name])[0]
        instances_ids = [i.instance_id for i in group.instances]
        reservations = ec2_conn.get_all_reservations(instances_ids)
        instances = [i for r in reservations for i in r.instances]
        dns_names = [i.public_dns_name for i in instances]
        print('\n'.join(dns_names))
    finally:
        ec2_conn.close()
        as_conn.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[Gist](https://gist.github.com/JamesMcMahon/9673227)

The answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/12592543/20774 was helpful in developing this script.

Comment: You should not store your access key and secret key in a config file.  Phyton SDK (aka both) share a config file in ~/.aws/config and ~/.aws/credentials and will use it automatically. Should your code from an EC2 instance instead, use an EC2 role and instance profile instead.

Comment: @SébastienStormacq I was not aware of that, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 15):

Here is a bash command that will give you the list of IP addresses of your instances in an AutoScaling group.

```
for ID in $(aws autoscaling describe-auto-scaling-instances --region us-east-1 --query AutoScalingInstances[].InstanceId --output text);
do
aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids $ID --region us-east-1 --query Reservations[].Instances[].PublicIpAddress --output text
done
```

(you might want to adjust the region and to filter per AutoScaling group if you have several of them)

On a higher level point of view - I would question the need to connect to individual instances  in an AutoScaling Group.  The dynamic nature of AutoScaling would encourage you to fully automate your deployment and admin processes.  To quote an AWS customer : "If you need to ssh to your instance, change your deployment process"

--Seb

Comment: For anyone looking to find the Private IP of any given instance in your ASG, change `--query Reservations[].Instances[].PublicIpAddress` in the above to `--query Reservations[].Instances[].PrivateIpAddress`. Works like a charm, thanks @Sebastien Stormacq

Comment: I use the instance id to check for flags in a shared EFS directory. If a flag is found it indicates that the instance should rsync its local directory to what's on EFS. This solves the problem of EFS mounted directories being too slow to be referenced directly by the application (WordPress /plugins in my case). I use lsyncd to (asynchronously) push any local changes to EFS as they happen and set the sync flag. My v1 didn't need the instance ids (it simply looked for any flag not matching its own id). v2 will only look for flags matching an instance id in the active auto scaling group.

Answer (score 4):

The [describe-auto-scaling-groups](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/autoscaling/describe-auto-scaling-groups.html) command from the AWS Command Line Interface looks like what you're looking for.

Edit: Once you have the instance IDs, you can use the [describe-instances](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-instances.html) command to fetch additional details, including the public DNS names and IP addresses.

Comment: Yeah I was looking into this, unfortunately it doesn't look like it gives Public DNS names or IPs as part of the response.

Comment: Upvoted this answer because describe-auto-scaling-groups is a lot faster than describe-auto-scaling-instances. you can get private IP address using describe-instances

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `describe-auto-scaling-instances` cli command, and query for your autoscale group name.

Example:

> aws autoscaling describe-auto-scaling-instances --region us-east-1
>   --query 'AutoScalingInstances[?AutoScalingGroupName==`YOUR_ASG`]' --output text

Hope that helps

Answer (score 4):

You can also use below command to fetch private ip address without any jq/awk/sed/cut

```
$ aws autoscaling describe-auto-scaling-instances --region us-east-1 --output text \
--query "AutoScalingInstances[?AutoScalingGroupName=='ASG-GROUP-NAME'].InstanceId" \
| xargs -n1 aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids $ID --region us-east-1 \
--query "Reservations[].Instances[].PrivateIpAddress" --output text
```

courtesy [this](https://serverfault.com/a/888012/502569)

Answer (score 0):

Use the below snippet for sorting out ASGs with specific tags and listing out its instance details.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import boto3

ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2', region_name='us-west-2')

def get_instances():
        client = boto3.client('autoscaling', region_name='us-west-2')
        paginator = client.get_paginator('describe_auto_scaling_groups')
        groups = paginator.paginate(PaginationConfig={'PageSize': 100})
        #print groups
        filtered_asgs = groups.search('AutoScalingGroups[] | [?contains(Tags[?Key==`{}`].Value, `{}`)]'.format('Application', 'CCP'))

        for asg in filtered_asgs:
                print asg['AutoScalingGroupName']
                instance_ids = [i for i in asg['Instances']]
                running_instances = ec2.instances.filter(Filters=[{}])
                for instance in running_instances:
                        print(instance.private_ip_address)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    get_instances()
```

Answer (score -1):

for ruby using aws-sdk gem v2
First create ec2 object as this:

ec2 = Aws::EC2::Resource.new(region: 'region',
   credentials: Aws::Credentials.new('IAM_KEY', 'IAM_SECRET')
   )

instances = []

```
ec2.instances.each do |i|
   p "instance id---", i.id
   instances << i.id
```

end

This will fetch all instance ids in particular region and can use more filters like ip_address.