# Get public DNS for aws_autoscaling_group instances

Tags: amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I want to output the public DNS of the EC2s that make up my auto scaling group:

```
resource "aws_launch_configuration" "instances" {
  image_id        = "ami-0fad7824ed21125b1"
  instance_type   = "${var.instance_type}"
  security_groups = ["${aws_security_group.security_group_ec2.id}"]
  key_name        = "${var.key_pair_name}"

  user_data = "${data.template_file.user_data.rendered}"

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}

resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "scaling_group" {
  launch_configuration = "${aws_launch_configuration.instances.id}"
  availability_zones   = ["${var.availability_zones_names}"]

  load_balancers    = ["${var.elb_id}"]
  health_check_type = "ELB"

  min_size = "${var.min_size}"
  max_size = "${var.max_size}"

  tags = {
    key                 = "Name"
    value               = "terraformUpAndRunning-${var.cluster_name}"
    propagate_at_launch = true
  }

  wait_for_capacity_timeout = "5m"
}
```

I have checked the [auto scaling group attributes](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/autoscaling_group.html#attributes-reference) in official Terraform documentation but can't think in any of those to get my aim... Is there any  way?

Comment: Instances are created asynchronously after the ASG is created, so I guess there's no way to do this.

Comment: Using `data.aws_instance` is also executed to early..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instances that are managed by an auto-scaling group are not managed by Terraform. Therefore it's unwise for Terraform to keep track of those ephemeral instances in it's state files. Ephemeral instances will come and go by their nature.

However, if you really *want* to use Terraform for this purpose there is a data source called [aws_instances](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/instances.html). This gives you the ability to query and list multiple instances.

You could also use [awscli](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/) to print out the instance details. Here's an example of that: [Getting a list of instances in an EC2 auto scale group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22535223/getting-a-list-of-instances-in-an-ec2-auto-scale-group/22557313#22557313).

Comment: You can also, assign a Load Balancer to the ASG and get the DNS of the ALB/ELB.