# How to fetch IP of instances in an Auto scaling group

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-cli, autoscaling

I have been trying to get IP details of all instances in each auto scaling groups which I have listed using paginator and printed using `print asg['AutoScalingGroupName']`

```
import boto
import boto3

client = boto3.client('autoscaling', region_name='us-west-2')
autoscale = boto.connect_autoscale()
ec2 = boto.connect_ec2()
paginator = client.get_paginator('describe_auto_scaling_groups')
page_iterator = paginator.paginate(PaginationConfig={'PageSize': 100}
)

filtered_asgs = page_iterator.search(
    'AutoScalingGroups[] | [?contains(Tags[?Key==`{}`].Value, `{}`)]'.format('Application', 'CCP')
)

for asg in filtered_asgs:
    print asg['AutoScalingGroupName']
        group = autoscale.get_all_groups(asg['AutoScalingGroupName'])[0]
        instance_ids = [i.instance_id for i in group.instances]
        reservations = ec2.get_all_instances(instance_ids)
        instances = [i for r in reservations for i in r.instances]
        print instances
```

Please help me to find out what I am missing here.

Comment: Have you checked [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12592543/1535071) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22544230/1535071) answers?

Comment: Yes, I added that to my script. You can see that I have replaced mygroupname with the ASG name in the loop. Seems like the the way I coded is incorrect. Do you have any suggestions ?.

Comment: The question is not clear to me. Do you get an error? Is it printing something at all? In what part of the whole process are you stuck?

Comment: This is the output.
`stg-ccp-asg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mar_test.py", line 17, in <module>
    group = autoscale.get_all_groups(asg['AutoScalingGroupName'])[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
`

When I tried to print group it is showing nothing. That means `group = autoscale.get_all_groups(asg['AutoScalingGroupName'])[0]` gives no ouptput.

Comment: Please see this output..

`dev-ccp-asg
[]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mar_test.py", line 19, in <module>
    instance_ids = [i.instance_id for i in group.instances]
AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'instances'`

It says no elements in that list 'group'

Comment: you should add this error output to your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Lorena, Your suggestions really helped.

I have iterated filtered the results correctly as below.

```
import boto3

ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2', region_name='us-west-2')

def get_instances():
        client = boto3.client('autoscaling', region_name='us-west-2')
        paginator = client.get_paginator('describe_auto_scaling_groups')
        groups = paginator.paginate(PaginationConfig={'PageSize': 100})
        #print groups
        filtered_asgs = groups.search('AutoScalingGroups[] | [?contains(Tags[?Key==`{}`].Value, `{}`)]'.format('Application', 'CCP'))

        for asg in filtered_asgs:
                print asg['AutoScalingGroupName']
                instance_ids = [i for i in asg['Instances']]
                running_instances = ec2.instances.filter(Filters=[{}])
                for instance in running_instances:
                        print(instance.private_ip_address)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    get_instances()
```

Comment: amazing, glad to help :)

Answer (score 2):

A little late, but here i post my version for this.

I made this for getting data of just the first auto-scale group that you get from calling describe_auto_scaling_groups, modify accordingly.

```
import boto3


ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
asg = boto3.client('autoscaling')

response= asg.describe_auto_scaling_groups(AutoScalingGroupNames=['myAutoScaleName',],)
groups=response.get("AutoScalingGroups")
instances=(groups[0].get('Instances'))

for i in instances:
    pubip=ec2.Instance(i.get('InstanceId')).public_ip_address
    print(pubip)
```

Answer (score 1):

This snippet should work, you just have to add your specific filters:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import boto3

ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')

def get_instances():
    client = boto3.client('autoscaling')
    paginator = client.get_paginator('describe_auto_scaling_groups')
    groups = paginator.paginate().build_full_result()

    for asg in groups['AutoScalingGroups']:
        print asg['AutoScalingGroupName']
        instance_ids = [i for i in asg['Instances']]
        running_instances = ec2.instances.filter(Filters=[{}])
        for instance in running_instances:
            print(instance.id, instance.public_dns_name, instance.private_ip_address)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    get_instances()
```

Comment: Filter I use is only for sorting ASGs as per its tags. Could you please suggest how do I bring in the following filter in your code.  
  
`filtered_asgs = page_iterator.search(
    'AutoScalingGroups[] | [?contains(Tags[?Key==`{}`].Value, `{}`)]'.format('Application', 'CCP')
)`
  
I tried by my own and is showing below error:  
  
`AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'search'`

Comment: You can get a hint of it [here](https://gist.github.com/sahilsk/dee8f6d0ed4e4cbecea4bc34c9c5e689)

Comment: I have worked with this filters for EC2 instances.  But this doesnt worked for me on ASGs using boto3. Thats how I found paginator technique which worked like charm. Your snippet is really good. But I am unable apply my ASG fliter in your code. When I do, it returns the above mentioned error. :(